# Getting getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND on npm run dev through Vagrant

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, vagrant, nuxt.js

I hope you're having a good day!

I'm relatively new to this stack, so please bear with me. Using `npm`, `Vue.js` with `Nuxt.js` and `Laravel`, working through the Ubuntu virtual machine on `Vagrant` on `macOS Catalina`.

Running `npm run dev`, everything seems to be fine, except when I manually refresh the page

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND domain.com domain.com:80

  at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
```

The setup is made by my friend programmer who's using Ubuntu locally—and I'm doing only the front-end part. Thing is, everything is working fine for them, but for me, on Mac it's a complete mess. We have a feeling that the cause is yet another Catalina security scrutiny, just not sure what it is exactly.

**What I already checked:**

- Locally on mac the `127.0.0.1 localhost` exists in `/etc/hosts`;
- Per Vagrant's recommendation, the Terminal on Mac is getting all the required permissions (as it asks);
- I saw advice somewhere to install a `vagrant-hostsmanager` plugin and sync the host files between systems, which I did, but not sure if it changed anything.

Not sure what else do I look up. I saw lots of topics mostly unanswered or people referring to incorrect proxy settings, but I don't think we're using any...

So asking for help here

Comment: That could be tough to debug. Why are you using a Linux VM if you are already using Unix? There's a lot that can go wrong. I've tried several setups for this kind of work and I can highly recommend Laravel's valet tool. Vagrant was good for working on windows but with WSL there's really no point using it for web development anymore.

Comment: Hey @Cobolt. Thanks! Basically, we're doing development locally—my colleague on his Ubuntu, and myself on macOS. The web app is to be deployed on DigitalOcean's Ubuntu.

Comment: @Cobolt, sorry if this is too blurry. What info can I share to find a solution? It is indeed tough, just looking up the errors doesn't give me many clues.

Comment: I have used that stack a lot. I will try do more research later after work but it could be many, many things. I don't have access to a Mac anymore as well. I understand telling you to use something else is not answering your question but sometimes the easiest solution is to start again (turn it on and off). Laravel Valet is very easy to setup and your machine will be saving on a lot of ram as it doesn't have to run an entire extra virtual OS.